# Firebase Logout On Batch Push

Tags: android, batch-file, firebase

I am creating an app on Android that uses Firebase as database and Batch for pushing notifications. Usually, when my app starts, it goes to the main page, a login activity. The activity verifies if a user is still logged in using:

```
Firebase dbRef = new Firebase(Constants.URL_DB);
AuthData auth = dbRef.getAuth();

if (auth != null) // Proceed with a logged in user
else // Show authentication layout
```

My problem is that when I get a notification from Batch, I click on the notification to go to the app but then I am not logged in as I should be... `auth == null`. I don't want my users to need to log in every time they get a push from Batch. Can I detect that the app started from a notification? How is that I lose authentication from Firebase?

Here is the onCreate and onResume of the MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initiating Batch
    Batch.onStart(this);

    // Initiating layout
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    // Setting database
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    // Unrelated stuff done here (Setting Views, etc)
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Getting login information from previous authentication.
    Firebase dbRef = new Firebase(Constants.URL_DB);
    AuthData auth = dbRef.getAuth();

    // I added the addAuthStateListener here

    if (auth != null) {
        goToHomePage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... that sounds unusual. Can you try to detect the authentication with a listener: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-monitoring-authentication It should do the same, but I wonder if you're somehow calling `getAuth()` before the state is known.

Comment: There's not enough code here to possibly guess the timing of when all this takes place. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: authData is null in `public void onAuthStateChanged(AuthData authData) {...}` since I am not logged in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right I found the problem. When I click on the notification, my MainActivity is called obviously. The thing is that when the user is logged in successfully, I start another Activity using:

`startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.SUCCESS);`

Now, `onActivityResult` is normally called to log out the user when the back button has been pressed on the home page. Otherwise, `onResume` is called and since the user is logged in, I would go straight back to the home page. BUT: when I click on a notification, somehow `onActivityResult` is called (probably because the activity stack gets trashed) and the user is logged out before resuming the activity.

So the solution is to log out the user in the `onBackPressed` of the home page activity. Then I don't need to `startActivityForResult` anymore.

```
// In the home page activity
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Firebase dbRef = new Firebase(Constants.URL_DB);
    dbRef.unauth();
    finish();
}
```